# tqdm to display download in human readable units

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, tqdm

I am using tqdm and requests to manage file download in Python. However I can't figure out how to make tqdm display the progress bar in human-readable format i.e. in MB/s.

Here is my code

```
import requests
import os
from tqdm import tqdm

def download_file(url, local_path="./"):
    local_filename = url.split('/')[-1]
    path = local_path + local_filename

    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    total_size = int(r.headers.get('content-length', 0))
    chunk_size = 32*1024
    with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
        # 1KB = 1024 bytes
        for chunk in tqdm(r.iter_content(chunk_size), total=total_size, unit_scale=True, 
                          unit_divisor=1024):
            if chunk:
                f.write(chunk)

    return path

weightLink = "https://pjreddie.com/media/files/yolov3.weights"
weigthPath = r"/PyTorch-YOLOv3/weights/"
weightLink = "https://pjreddie.com/media/files/yolov3.weights"
download_file(weightLink, weigthPath)
```

With above code, the progression of the downloaded size is wrong and I see the download speed in `it/s`. I would like to have everything displayed in terms of `MB/s`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Pass extra parameters for tqdm `unit='B', unit_scale=True, unit_divisor=1024`.

## Example:

```
from tqdm import tqdm

for i in tqdm(range(9999999), unit='B', unit_scale=True, unit_divisor=1024):
    pass
```

## Output:

> 100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 9.54M/9.54M [00:03<00:00, 2.66MB/s]

Comment: You probably want to use `unit_divisor=1000` (the default) to stay consistent with SI units (kB, MB, ...). With `unit_divisor=1024`, you would want to use the IEC standard (KiB, MiB, ...). See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte#Multiple-byte_units) for details.

Comment: @SagiZiv the easy (and hacky) way would be to use `iB`, but this would produce incorrect outputs for any values `< 1024 * 1024`. To do it properly, you would want to overwrite [`tqdm.format_sizeof`](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/blob/6791e8c5b3d6c30bdd2060c346996bfb5a6f10d1/tqdm/std.py#L259-L286).